# Another Google Maps Fragment Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, fragment, android-inflate

I have been having this issue for over a week now where any attempt to call the 'onCreateView' method of SupportMapFragment class causes a runtime error. I have extended the SupportMapFragment class for debugging reasons. The application will compile and run, but when told to display a Google map fragment, immediately crashes with the familiar "unable to inflate map fragment" error.

Notes:

- I use SupportMapFragment with FragmentActivity
- Google API Level 10 is the Target
- The 'return' statement under the SupportMapFragment class code (below) is where the issue occurs (known because of 5th LogCat output)
- The Manifest file contains the meta data element for the Google Play Services Version
- The Manifest file contains the meta data element for the Google Maps V2 API Key
- The Manifest file contains the meta data element for GLES Version 2.0
- The Manifest file contains the permission com.google.android.providers.gfs.permission.READ_GSERVICES (despite what LogCat says)
- I have downloaded the Google Play Services from the SDK Manager
- Android Private Libraries, Google APIs [Android2.2.3], and Android Dependencies are part of the project Java Build Path and are checked
- The google-play-services_lib is a library in Properties -> Android
- Run (and crashed) on AVD using Google API Level 4.2.2
- Run (and crashed) on physical device using Google API Level 4.2.2

Manifest

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.softcrypt"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gfs.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Libraries -->
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true"/>

    <!-- Activities -->
    <activity 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".SoftCryptMapActivity"
        android:label="Map"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.softcrypt.SoftCryptMapActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Meta Data -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/apiKey" />
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

</application>
```

LogCat

```
04-30 18:08:30.367: D/SoftCrypt(1555): SoftCryptMapActivity Started
04-30 18:08:30.787: D/dalvikvm(1555): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 207K, 9% free 3178K/3456K, paused 40ms, total 42ms
04-30 18:08:30.857: I/Google Maps Android API(1555): Google Play services client version: 4323000
04-30 18:08:30.887: I/Google Maps Android API(1555): Google Play services package version: 4323030
04-30 18:08:30.927: D/SoftCrypt(1555): Creating MapFragment...
04-30 18:08:30.967: D/AndroidRuntime(1555): Shutting down VM
04-30 18:08:30.967: W/dalvikvm(1555): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3b0dba8)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): Process: com.softcrypt, PID: 1555
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softcrypt/com.softcrypt.SoftCryptMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.softcrypt.SoftCryptMapActivity.onCreate(SoftCryptMapActivity.java:33)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     ... 11 more
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at maps.e.ci.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at maps.e.ay.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at maps.e.bh.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at maps.e.bg.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at etu.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at com.softcrypt.SoftCryptMapFragment.onCreateView(SoftCryptMapFragment.java:24)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1093)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1195)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-30 18:08:30.987: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):     ... 21 more
```

map_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="com.softcrypt.SoftCryptMapFragment"/>
```

FragmentActivity Subclass

```
public class SoftCryptMapActivity extends FragmentActivity

{

private GoogleMap map;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
    Log.d(super.getString(R.string.app_name), "SoftCryptMapActivity Started");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Check for Service Availability
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext()) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)

        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        }

    super.setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    Log.d(super.getString(R.string.app_name), "Content View Set");
    map = ((SupportMapFragment)super.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();

    // Check for Service Availability
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext()) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)

        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        }   

    }

}
```

SupportMapFragment Subclass

```
public class SoftCryptMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment

{

GoogleMap map;
FragmentManager fm;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
    Log.d(super.getString(R.string.app_name), "Creating MapFragment...");
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add user permission `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES` in you Manifest to use the `MAP API`

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Your crash log , clearly shows that.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
```

Comment: I meant to post the Manifest file along with all of the other code. I'll look at what you said, but I may have already added it. Thanks.